# Equal distribution of marks in group of students

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have the database of students of a particular school.

```
student_name |math | science| english| social
---------------------------------------------
Aakas        | 80  |  70    |   90   |   55
Aphi         | 30  |  80    |   67   |   79
Geeta        | 60  |  89    |   95   |   87
pradip       | 70  |  78    |   67   |   65
Nikita       | 45  |  78    |   90   |   48
Shanti       | 69  |  90    |   67   |   84
```

the students numbers *n* is say 1000.

The thing I need to do is divide the student into 'm' groups(for example m is 250). Such that each subject of a group should have nearly average marks. For the above the average marks of math is 59(for given six students) for considering math only. If we divide six students into two groups each containing 3 students. Group 1 = {Aakas, Abhi, Geeta} group 2 = {Pradip, Nikita, Shanti}

Group 1 has average 56.67 in math which is near to 59 group 2 has average 61.33 in math which is near to 59

Which is the case considering math only. We have to consider for all subjects such that each group have an average marks near to the average of individual subject of whole students. How to solve it?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It really is not clear what you are trying to do.  Are you simply trying to put the four columns into quintiles, for instance?

Comment: 1. Normalise your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 1 subject and want 2 students per group, then you would pair the highest scoring student with the lowest scoring student and the 2nd highest scoring student with the 2nd lowest scoring student and so on to get a set of groups where the average of each pair will be close to the average of the score of all students.

Similarly, for 250 groups, or 4 students per group, you can rank each student across all their subjects and group the top 2 ranked students with the bottom ranked 2 students and the top 3rd and 4th ranked students with the bottom 3rd and 4th students and so on.

Below is a query that ranks your students by their total math and science scores. You can adapt this query to include more subjects.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4667/1

```
select t1.student_name, math, science, math_rank.rn, science_rank.rn,
 math_rank.rn + science_rank.rn as total_rank,
 @group_number := if(@rn % 4 = 0, @group_number + 1, @group_number) group_number,
 @rn := (@rn + 1)
from Table1 t1
join (
    select stuadent_name, (@rn_math := @rn_math + 1) rn
    from Table1 
    cross join (select @rn_math := 0) t2
    order by math desc
) math_rank on t1.student_name = math_rank.student_name
join (
    select student_name, (@rn_science := @rn_science + 1) rn
    from Table1 
    cross join (select @rn_science := 0) t2
    order by science desc
) science_rank on t1.student_name = science_rank.student_name 
cross join (select @group_number := 1, @rn := 1) t2
order by total_rank
```